# MVC Custom Validation for List on Client Side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to write a custom validator that works on the client side that validates that all checkboxes have been ticked.

Here's the declaration on the model:

```
[DeclarationsAccepted(ErrorMessage = "You must tick all declarations")]        
    public IList<DeclarationQuestion> DeclarationQuestions { get; set; }
```

And here's the attribute:

```
public class DeclarationsAccepted : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        var questions = value as IList<DeclarationQuestion>;

        if (questions != null && questions.All(c => c.Answer))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return new ValidationResult("You must accepted all declarations to continue");
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var modelClientValidationRule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ValidationType = "declarationsaccepted",
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName)
        };            
        yield return modelClientValidationRule;
    }
}
```

So far so good, works server side.

For the client I'm wiring this up as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('declarationsaccepted', function (value, element, params) {

        //Implement logic here to check all boxes are ticked
        console.log(value);

        return false;
    }, '');


    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('declarationsaccepted', {}, function (options) {
        options.rules['declarationsaccepted'] = true;
        options.messages['declarationsaccepted'] = options.message;
    });
```

I'm displaying the checkboxes like this:

```
@{ var questionIndex = 0; }
        @foreach (var question in Model.DeclarationQuestions)
        {

                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.DeclarationQuestions[questionIndex].Answer, new { id = "DeclarationQuestions" + questionIndex})

            questionIndex++;
        }
```

And then displaying the validation message using this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.DeclarationQuestions)
```

When I submit the form the message is displayed but only after a post back to the server. Is there any way to get this to work on the client side?

Comment: Is any validation working client side? if not you need to include  jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.

Comment: Yes validation is working client side and I am able to apply the attribute to other properties e.g. a text input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you will not get client side validation is because the html helpers generate `data-val-*` attributes for controls associated with properties. `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` reads those attributes when the form is parsed and using rules, displays an error message in the appropriate element generated by `ValidationMessageFor()` associated with that control (it does this by matching up the `id` attributes of the elements - the error message is generated in a span with `<span for="TheIdOfTheAssociatedControl" ...>`).

You don't (and cant) generate a control for property `DeclarationQuestions` (only for properties of each item in `DeclarationQuestions` so there is nothing that can be matched up.

You could handle this by including your own error message placeholder and intercepting the `.submit` event

html (add css to style `#conditions-error` as `display:none;`)

```html
<span id="delarations-error" class="field-validation-error">
  <span>You must accept all declarations to continue.</span>
</span>
```

Script

```
var declarationsError = $('#delarations-error');
$('form').submit(function() {
  var isValid = $('.yourCheckBoxClass').not(':checked') == 0;
  if(!isValid) {
    declarationsError.show(); // display error message
    return false; // prevent submit
  }
});

$('.yourCheckBoxClass').change(function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    declarationsError.hide(); // hide error message
  }
});
```

Side note: You loop for generating the checkboxes should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.DeclarationQuestions.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DeclarationQuestions[i].Answer, new { id = "DeclarationQuestions" + i})
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll implement using your suggested solution above