# validating client with multiple controls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following code for multiselect dropdown but my isssue is how do display the error message that i have added to the VM class in the client side

ViewModel class **OrderModel**

```
 public class OrderModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CatId { get; set; }                
        [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage="please select an item")]
        public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }

        public OrderModel()
        {
            Products = new List<ProductModel>();
        }
    }
```

the **ProductModel** class

```
 public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ProdName { get; set; }
    }
```

the **categorymodel**

```
 public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

**actions of the controller Home**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     return View();
 }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OrderModel order)
{
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //write code here
                }
                else 
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Model error");
                }


                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
}
```

**the view**

```
@model Selectmany_test.Models.OrderModel

@{  

    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new  { id="frm" }))
{ 
    <fieldset>
        <label>Product Categories</label>
        <select id="prodcats"></select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.CatId)
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label>Products</label>
        <select id="prods" multiple="multiple"></select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Products)
    </fieldset>    
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Send" id="btnSend" />
    </fieldset>
}


@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>*@
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var form = $('#frm');
            $('#prods').multiselect({ includeSelectAllOption: true });

            $('#btnSend').click(function () {

                if (form.valid())
                {
                    //ajax to call Create() to save but how do i make the form invalid if the user failed to select one from multi-select dropdown
                }
            });


        $.ajax({    
            url:'@Url.Action("GetCategories","Home")',
            method:'get',
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#prodcats').empty();
                $('#prodcats').append('<option>select fruit</option>');
                $(data).each(function (index, item) {                    
                    $('#prodcats').append( $('<option />', {text:item.CategoryName, value:item.Id}) );
                })
                $('#prods').empty();
                $('#prods').append('<option>Select product</option>');
                $('#prods').prop({ disabled: true });
            },
            error: function(x,y,z){
                alert('error');
            }    
        });

        $('#prodcats').change(function (evt) {
            var x = $(this).val();
            console.log(x);
            if (x == 'select fruit')
            {
                $('#prods').empty();
                $('#prods').append('<option>select product</option>');
                $('#prods').prop({ disabled: true });
            }
            else
            {
                $('#prods').empty();
                $('#prods').append('<option>select product</option>');
                $('#prods').prop({ disabled: false });
                var Id = $('#prodcats').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetProductsByCatId", "Home")',
                    method: 'GET',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.Stringgyfy({ 'catId': Id }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
                            $('#prods').append($('<option />', { text:item.ProdName, value:item.Id}));
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (x,y,z) { }
                });
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
    }
```

all the ajax get methods works but how do stop the save method call, if the form is invalid. The form becomes invalid if the user failed to select category and select at least one from the multiselect 'prods' also as mentioned proviousely i want to display model error message 'please select an item'

Comment: You cannot get client side validation for a collection of complex objects using jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive. You need to implement you own script to prevent the form submission. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036287/mvc-custom-validation-for-list-on-client-side/29043225#29043225) for an example

Comment: @StephenMuecke Assume i have a simple collection to accept the orders eg> instead of sending the List<Product> i want send a list of ProdId i.e.:List<int> how this validation should be done?

Comment: The same as per the link in my last comment. You need to write your own script.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so steve to if i get it right if there is any kind of Listbox or dropped down with muti-select, the the error messages i add to Data Annoation is useless becuase it does not work on collection like in my case. so even there is model validation written using data annotations i must write my own custom script for validation

Comment: If you using `ListBoxFor()` and binding to a `int[]` property with a `[Required]` attribute, you will get a client side error if you do not select any items, but a `[MinLength]` attribute will not work.

Comment: @StephenMuecke im not using ListBoxFor() and i dont know how to generated a dropdown list with checkboxes with ListBoxFor() im using the bootstrap-multiselect plugin to generate the dropwdown. in my case i have no option but to go with the client custom js scripts, am i correct?

Comment: You can still use `ListBoxFor()` to generate the `<select>` element and attach your plugin to it (and add the associated `ValidationMessageFor()`). Although you will probably need to reconfigure the `$.validator` to validate hidden elements.